# Problem building react-native app to ios using EAS due to Incompatible POD versions

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I've been trying to build this app on EAS for a while now and I'm stuck on this compatibility error that says:

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":

I've tried removing the podfile and redownloading it many times with different versions of my package-json (following every Stack Overflow question) and it still does not work. Can somebody figure out what versions I need to fix in order to build?

Here is the "Fail Build" error that I'm receiving on expo:

Build failed: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:

- Versions in the cached Podfile.lock do not match required values in Podspecs of some installed libraries. To fix this, you can re-run build command with "--clear-cache" option, or select "Clear cache and retry build" on the build page.
- Some of the pods used in your project depend on different versions of the same pod. See logs for more information.

Here is the error I get under "install pods":

Using Expo modules
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXImageLoader
Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `forepay`: RNCCheckbox, RNFBApp, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNImageCropPicker, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, react-native-cameraroll, react-native-document-picker, react-native-image-resizer, react-native-netinfo, and react-native-webview
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
CocoaPods 1.12.0 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods`
For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.12.0
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/Core (= 9.5.0) was resolved to 9.5.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 9.5.0)
RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 16.7.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.3.0)
Error: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:

- Versions in the cached Podfile.lock do not match required values in Podspecs of some installed libraries. To fix this, you can re-run build command with "--clear-cache" option, or select "Clear cache and retry build" on the build page.
- Some of the pods used in your project depend on different versions of the same pod. See logs for more information.

And here is my package.json file:

{
"name": "forepay",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.2.1",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.14",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
"@stream-io/flat-list-mvcp": "^0.10.2",
"expo": "^48.0.0",
"expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.3.1",
"expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.1.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"firebase": "^9.15.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.3",
"react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.3",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
"react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0",
"react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
"react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.2.1",
"react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
"react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
"react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.15",
"react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
"reshake": "^1.2.4",
"rn-swipe-button": "^1.3.8",
"source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
"stream-chat": "^8.2.1",
"stream-chat-expo": "^5.7.0",
"stream-chat-react-native": "^5.7.0",
"styled-components": "^5.3.6",
"unique-names-generator": "^4.7.1",
"urix": "^0.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}

Answer (score 0):

In folder IOS-> pod update Firebase/CoreOnly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).